# Bypassing in-line if statements? Python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x, logic

So I'm making a video player that automatically chooses the next video based on some weighted probabilities. When a video comes in, it reads all its metatags from a csv, then looks up the next match after the probability rolls. I had all the various metatag checks programmed in-line with if statements and for loops, but the client has just asked to have on and off switches for each of the filters and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the most efficient way of approaching the problem.

I'm still fairly green with Python, so I figured I'd ask before trying to do something the worst way possible. I'm wondering (if there isn't a way to do this that I just don't know of yet) if it would be better to have the on and off switches interrupt and change the variables before they get to this point, so that for example when the on switch is on, a list of every possible color would be assigned to the variable color, so that it always passes and no videos get rejected from the color, thus keeping the same basic formatting.

Below is a simplified version of what I kind of have going on, for readabilities sake. Before it, the program gets all the variables it needs from the csv, and after the final print, the ones that pass get added to a list of good choices which is randomly pulled from:

```
for eachrow in table:
    Answer = False
    for eachcell in eachrow:
        if  color == req_color:
            if speed == req_speed:
                if exclusion == req_exclusion:
                    print ('No pass!')
                else:
                    Answer = True
                    print ('All attributes match')
    if Answer:
        print ('This passes')
```

Cheers!

Comment: It's not clear to me at all what you're asking.

Comment: The assignment `if exclusion = exclusion:` won't work. Use `if exclusion_1 = exclusion_2:` instead. Comparing a value with itself is of limited usability as well.

Comment: @glglgl: `if foo = bar:` doesn' t work at all; assignment is not an expression.

Comment: @Wooble This is what I intended to say. Unfortunately, the error devil has bitten me as well; I intended to say `if exclusion_1 == exclusion_2:` :-/

Comment: Guys, so sorry about the confusion, I was up late working, thanks to jsbueno for the edit to make it actually make sense!

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you are looking for `continue` ?

> The continue statement is used to tell Python to skip the rest of the statements in the current loop block and to continue to the next iteration of the loop.

http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue

Comment: I was using continue and break before. But would that work in the in-line setup, or would continue jump out of the for loop before it made it to the end?

Comment: continue exits the currently running for loop, so if there are further items to be processed in that loop they won't be processed. If you are inside a nested loop then that loop will continue. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Flow_control#Breaking.2C_continuing_and_the_else_clause_of_loops

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use [continue](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). Continue is sort of like break, except where break terminates the loop, continue just skips the rest of the current run of the loop and starts the next.

I can't really tell what you are trying to do, but you could try something like this:

```
testsToRun = ['speed','color']
for row in table:
    Answer = False
    for cell in row:
        if  cell['color'] == color and 'color' in testsToRun:
            print ('No pass!')
            continue
        if cell['speed'] == speed and 'speed' in testsToRun:
            print ('No pass!')
            continue
        if cell['exclusion'] == exclusion and 'exclusion' in testsToRun:
            print ('No pass!')
            continue
        Answer=True
        print ('All attributes match')
    if Answer:
        print ('This passes')
```

Comment: That looks cleaner than mine, thanks, but how would I control the on and off of each one? By having them included in testsToRun if the switch for that filter is on?

Comment: @ElburzSorkhabi I wrote it in a way that I find to be readable, but it performs string comparison every time a test is run, if you run many of these tests then the time to do that comparison may be significant and a more efficient method should be used. I don't know too much about your situation, so there may be a better way to do this based on how you store the tests that you want to run. That being said, the tests that are run are the ones in `testsToRun`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, everyone. I solved the issue by actually going back to where the variables are defined. I set it so that when its off, it sends all the possible variables to the if, so that it always passes if its off. That way when the switch is on and it takes the user input, it selectively passes things through. I thought about other options but since this prototype has to have a quick turn around time, this seemed like the best bet.

Thanks again!